# how to hide scrollbar on toggle class

Tags: jquery, html, css, class, toggle

HTML The Markup Structure

```
<div class="box" style="background:pink">
 <span class="inner-text">pink</span>
```

CSS with toggle **class**

```
.test {
  overflow:hidden;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:10;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width: 100vw !important;
  height: 100%;
}
```

jQuery toggle is working i want to hide the scroll y

```
$('.box').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('test');
});
```

[image: picture here]

Comment: do you want like this? http://jsbin.com/tuyuqo

Answer (score 0):

You're using Jquery and you need to add link to Jquery inside head tag

Everything else works fine

```
...
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

You can use plain Javascript for click event as explained :

[HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add css rule of overflow-y:hidden after the class toggle

`$(this).toggleClass('test').css("overflow-y","hidden");`

[image: Picture]